# Just in time Compilation like Memoization?

Tags: compiler-construction, jit, memoization

Im trying to understand Just in time compilation/interpretation, and a head of time compilation? Would i be correct in saying that Just in time is sort of like memoization? in that it reuses the "solutions," that is machine or byte code, of the parts that it recognises as being repeated?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation should help

Comment: I looked at that, it was a bit over my head, so is JIT only relevant for interpreted languages?

Comment: Both techniques are used for intermediate languages, the JIT compilation is the process of translating intermediate language to native language progressively during application execution, that is, when a portion of an intermediate language is called, the JITter will check if it has been compiled before, if not it compiles it into native code on the fly and mark that portion of IL code as compiled so the next time it will be executed directly. On the other hand, the AOT compilation is the process of translating all the IL code into native code before the app starts at compile time or at runtime

Answer (score 0):

No that would not be correct.

Lets look at what these tools do when you threw some bytecode on them. (In very simple terms)

### Interpreter

A Interpreter looks a bytecode finds out what he has to do, does it and then moves on to the next bytecode. Thats quite simple and happens all at runtime.

### AOT Compiler

A AOT Compiler is what is mostly refered to when people talk about a compiler. When you are compiling he looks at the bytecode you give him and finds out what nativ code (assembler) he has to generate. So when you then run this nativ code you don't have to find out what to do like with an interpreter and thats why its faster.

### JIT Compiler:

The idea of a JIT is that most of the time in your programm is spent in loops. So when you have a loop that has 100 iteration and in every iteration you you add some stuff the interpreter has to look at what you want to do every time and do it. The JIT looks at the loop and sais "I don't have to find out what that does a 100 times over agian. Im just going to compile this bit of code. Then he does what a normal compiler does and generate some nativ code and runs that.

A JIT often works together with an interpreter. The interpreter finds that something is a loop and then passes that to the JIT and after the loop it keeps on interpreting.

The implmentations of Java and .NET don't use an interpreter, thats possible too.
luajit, pypy and the JS implementation in firefox do have an interpreter.

(If you should have an interpreter or not is subject of debate)

Hope that helps.